# JavaScript output of a string instead of undefined?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting undefined instead of a String on return of the answer - though it is the right correct characters being logged. How do I get it to output a definite string?

```
var greet = function(name) {
   let  first = String(name. charAt(0). toUpperCase());
    let second = String(name.slice(1));

    console.log('Hello ' + first + second + '!');
    }
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Because you don't return anything, so the return-value is undefined.

Comment: What return?...

Comment: You should instead of using `console.log` be using `return`, and then do `console.log(greet('gemma'));`

Comment: Your code works just fine. I just tested.

Comment: Read this if the above doesn't make sense: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Return_values

Comment: Thank you! It worked as soon as I added the return and consoled.log outside of the function. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to return a value, so the return-value is `undefined`.

```js
var greet = function(name) {
    let  first = String(name. charAt(0). toUpperCase());
    let second = String(name.slice(1));

    return 'Hello ' + first + second + '!';
}

console.log(greet('Gemma'));
```

Comment: Great thank you. This worked. I must remember to return the values going forward.

Answer (score 0):

The console will print the result of evaluating an expression. You can notice if you set

> let name = 'john'

it will print undefined in the very next line.
That is also happening here. First it is printing your value, then it print undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is working fine - you just need to invoke it and feed its argument with a name...

[for the result look in the console]

```js
var greet = function(name) {
  let first = String(name.charAt(0).toUpperCase());
  let second = String(name.slice(1));

  console.log('Hello ' + first + second + '!');
}
;
greet("henky");
```

Comment: Useful to know that it works in a real life scenario, which is most important. It was in a coding software scenario which was looking at a specific answer and matching it against that. Returning the answer worked, as the console log was then invoked in the function. Thank you. Your help is appreciated